# MODX - user profile photo upload - don't remove original uploaded photo entry

Tags: modx

I have the following page snippet and form configured to allow users to upload photos to their profile. When a user updates his profile and does not specify a image, the original image that was uploaded is removed from the profiles extended fields. It goes back to blank.

Question: Is there a way to prevent this from happening. Want to allow the user to update profile, but not remove the image URL that was previously uplaoded.

**SNIPPET**

```
<?php
// initialize output;
$output = true;
  // get the current user name to create the file name as  
$userName = $modx->user->get('username');

// valid extensions
$ext_array = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

// create unique path for this form submission
$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/';

// you can create some logic to automatically
// generate some type of folder structure here.
// the path that you specify will automatically
// be created by the script if it doesn't already
// exist.

// EXAMPLE:
// this would put all file uploads into a new,
// unique folder every day.
// $uploadpath = 'assets/'uploads/'.date('Y-m-d').'/';

// get full path to unique folder
$target_path = $modx->config['base_path'] . $uploadpath;

// get uploaded file names:
$submittedfiles = array_keys($_FILES);

// loop through files
foreach ($submittedfiles as $sf) {

  // Get Filename and make sure its good.
  $filename = basename( $_FILES[$sf]['name'] );

  // Get file's extension
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $ext = mb_strtolower($ext); // case insensitive

  // is the file name empty (no file uploaded)
  if($filename != '') {

    // is this the right type of file?
    if(in_array($ext, $ext_array)) {

      //create file called the user name + pic
      $filename = $userName . "pic".'.'.$ext  ;

      // full path to new file
      $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;

      // create directory to move file into if it doesn't exist
      mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);
      if(file_exists($myTarget)) {
      chmod($myTarget,0755); //Change the file permissions if allowed
      unlink($myTarget); //remove the file
  }

      // is the file moved to the proper folder successfully?
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sf]['tmp_name'], $myTarget)) {
        // set a new placeholder with the new full path (if you need it in subsequent hooks)
        $hook->setValue($sf, $uploadpath . $filename);
        // set the permissions on the file
        if (!chmod($myTarget, 0644)) { /*some debug function*/ }

          } else {
        // File not uploaded
        $errorMsg = 'There was a problem uploading the file.';
        $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
        $output = false; // generate submission error
      }

      } else {
      // File type not allowed
          $errorMsg = 'Type of file not allowed.';
      $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
      $output = false; // generate submission error
        }

  // if no file, don't error, but return blank
  } else {
      $hook->setValue($sf, '');
  }

}

return $output;
```

**RESOURCE**

```
[[!UpdateProfile? &useExtended=`1`  &postHooks=`redirect_profile_update` &preHooks=`user_profile_image`]]

<div class="update-profile">
    <div class="updprof-error">[[+error.message]]</div>
    [[+login.update_success:if=`[[+login.update_success]]`:is=`1`:then=`[[%login.profile_updated? &namespace=`login` &topic=`updateprofile`]]`]]

    <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />

        <label for="fullname"><i class="icon-user"></i> <strong>[[!%login.fullname? &namespace=`login` &topic=`updateprofile`]]</strong>
            <span class="error">[[+error.fullname]]</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="[[+fullname]]" />

        <label for="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> <strong>[[!%login.email]]</strong>
            <span class="error">[[+error.email]]</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="[[+email]]" />


       <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="label"><img src="[[+nomination_file:phpthumbof=`w=120&h=120&zc=1&fltr[]=ric|20|20`
]]" /></div> <span class="error">[[+fi.error.nomination_file]]</span>
        <div class="input"><input id="nomination_file" name="nomination_file" type="file" value="[[+fi.nomination_file]]" maxlength="100000" /></div>
    </div>

        <br class="clear" />

       <button class="btn-info btn btn-large" type="submit" name="login-updprof-btn">Update Profile</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember exactly how formIt works, but try removing the `fi.` prefix from the **value** placeholder here:

```
<div class="input"><input id="nomination_file" name="nomination_file" type="file" value="[[+nomination_file]]" maxlength="100000" /></div>
```

That way the input should be populated with the existing image path which will be resubmitted if another image is not uploaded.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, although that does not seem to work.

Comment: I've just had a look at your hook code. I guess this is where the problem is: `$hook->setValue($sf, '');` You're resetting the field if no file is explicitly uploaded. You could remove this line entirely, in which case the image would remain set until you replace it with a new one (or add a button to remove it).

Comment: that breaks the snippet. Do you think there is a way to change that so that if not file is chosen, the original is left intact

Comment: Which lines did you remove? You should have left a closing curly bracket under the comment `// if no file, don't error, but return blank`

Comment: ah yes I see, I left one one curly bracket. Unfortunately that still removes the picture. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works

PHP snippet

```
<?php
// initialize output;
$output = true;
// get the current user name to for dicroty placement
$userName = $modx->user->get('username');

// valid extensions
$ext_array = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

// create unique path for this form submission
$uploadpath = 'assets/userfiles/' . $userName .'/';

// get full path to unique folder
$target_path = $modx->config['base_path'] . $uploadpath;

// get uploaded file names:
$submittedfiles = array_keys($_FILES);


//get exsisting user profile data for Profile_Photos
$fields = $modx->user->getOne('Profile')->get('extended');
$Photo_fields = $fields['Profile_Photos'];

// loop through files
foreach ($submittedfiles as $sf) {

  // Get Filename and make sure its good.
  $filename = basename( $_FILES[$sf]['name'] );

  // Get file's extension
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $ext = mb_strtolower($ext); // case insensitive

  if($filename != '') {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'in file name loop'.$filename);
                    // is this the right type of file?
    if(in_array($ext, $ext_array)) {
      //create file called the filename that has been sanitized
      $filename = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9.]+/i", "-", $filename));
      //$filename = $filename . '.'.$ext  ;


      // full path to new file
      $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;

      // create directory to move file into if it doesn't exist
      mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);
      if(file_exists($myTarget)) {
        chmod($myTarget,0755); //Change the file permissions if allowed
        unlink($myTarget); //remove the file
      }

      // is the file moved to the proper folder successfully?
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sf]['tmp_name'], $myTarget)) {
        // set a new placeholder with the new full path (if you need it in subsequent hooks)
        $hook->setValue($sf, $uploadpath . $filename);
        // set the permissions on the file
        if (!chmod($myTarget, 0644)) { /*some debug function*/ }  
      } 
      else {
        // File not uploaded
        $errorMsg = 'There was a problem uploading the file.';
        $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
        $output = false; // generate submission error
      }
    } 
    else {
      // File type not allowed
      $errorMsg = 'Type of file not allowed.';
      $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
      $output = false; // generate submission error
    }
  } 
  else {
    //check to see if there is exsisting photofields value and return value if so
    if ($Photo_fields != '')
    {
      $hook->setValue($sf, $Photo_fields);

    }
    else{       
      // if no file, don't error, but return blank
      // is the file name empty (no file uploaded) and exsiting photofields empty
      $hook->setValue($sf, '');
    }
  }
}
return $output;
```

Change profile Form

```
[[!UpdateProfile? &useExtended=`1`  &postHooks=`redirect_profile_update` &preHooks=`user_profile_image`]]

<div class="update-profile">
    <div class="updprof-error">[[+error.message]]</div>
    [[+login.update_success:if=`[[+login.update_success]]`:is=`1`:then=`[[%login.profile_updated? &namespace=`login` &topic=`updateprofile`]]`]]

    <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />

        <label for="fullname"><i class="icon-user"></i> <strong>[[!%login.fullname? &namespace=`login` &topic=`updateprofile`]]</strong>
            <span class="error">[[+error.fullname]]</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="[[+fullname]]" />

        <label for="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> <strong>[[!%login.email]]</strong>
            <span class="error">[[+error.email]]</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="[[+email]]" />


       <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="label"><img src="[[+Profile_Photos:phpthumbof=`w=120&h=120&zc=1&fltr[]=ric|20|20`
]]" /></div> <span class="error">[[+fi.error.Profile_Photos]]</span>
        <div class="input"><input id="Profile_Photos" name="Profile_Photos" type="file" value="[[+fi.Profile_Photos]]" maxlength="100000" /></div>
    </div>

        <br class="clear" />

       <button class="btn-info btn btn-large" type="submit" name="login-updprof-btn">Update Profile</button>
    </form>
</div>
```